# Is hug a kind of physical touch?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

This may sound silly but is hug a kind of physical touch?

Because in Chinese we often see hug more than just a kind of physical touch. By touch we often mean touch your hand, arm, shoulder and more importantly hug is typically to express affection while touch normally does not convey that feeling. Besides, I find we Chinese people are not used to hug (yet).

But do you see hug a kind of touch ?

--- update ---

I know I asked a silly question so I think I need to give some further explanation. This question was triggered by my son's English test, [check here](https://www.gaokzx.com/c/202303/68784_9.html)  43 Q "**Apart from touch, what other way(s) do you often use to express your love and care.**"

My son wrote "I would show my love and care by **hugging** someone..." and he got **zero** for this question. lol

If  you were his teacher would you think his answer was wrong and gives him a zero ?

Hence the question.

[image: the exam]

Comment: Have you looked up *hug* in a few dictionaries? [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hug) | [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hug) | [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hug).

Comment: A hug is a physical touch and a hug is also more than a physical touch.  If I said, "Touch me," and your response was to hug me, that would be an odd response by you.  I would have expected you to touch my hand or shoulder.  But if you ask me if a hug is a touch, I will tell you that it is because people *touch* when they hug.

Comment: Yes I looked up hug in some dictionaries but I can't find a clear answer.

Comment: Is your problem that "touch" generally suggests a lighter touch (brushing past someone, stroking, tapping gently), rather than a more forceful contact (punching, grabbing, kissing passionately, lying on top off)? "Touch" can refer to any contact but it's more common in some situations than others. If someone hugged you, that would be a touch, but you might prefer to say something else, especially if it was forceful or against your will (e.g. "He grabbed me").

Comment: https://edition.cnn.com/2018/10/03/health/hugs-study-relationships-wellbeing-trnd/index.html see images: [friends hugging](https://www.google.com/search?q=friends+hugging&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwj0x_yA4o_-AhXaJMUKHRCGC-EQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=friends+hugging&gs_lcp=img&ei=ENorZPT_AdrJlAaQjK6IDg&bih=628&biw=1117)

Comment: @StuartF I feel a bit embarrassed to ask the question and since you have given me valuable comments several times I updated the question to let you know why I had this question in the first place.

Comment: I updated the question to show why I have this question.

Comment: "Apart from touch" Hugging is a form of physical contact. I would have suggested **listening** and **nodding sympathetically**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hug involves physical contact. A hug is when you wrap your arms around someone, usually as a way of showing affection.  So when you hug someone you make physical contact.

A touch is also a physical contact, but a touch generally suggests a lighter contact, which can be affectionate or not.

There are lots of actions that involve some type of physical contact: grabbing, slapping, kissing, punching, pinching ... most of these involve more contact than a light touch.  So if two people have a rule that they don't touch each other, it would also ban grabbing, slapping, kissing... and hugging.

If you were asked for "ways to show affection that don't involve touch" then "hugging" would not be correct.  Hugging aways implies touch. It would be incorrect to use any of the forms of affection that involve physical contact such as "high-five", "pat on the shoulder", "warm handshake". Correct answers could be "kind words", "blown kisses", "love letters", "heart emoji on instagram" and so on.

I don't know what mark scheme (rubric) the teacher is following - But I note that in the image, "hugs" are given explicitly as an example of comforting by touch "studies in the power of touch [...show...] offering hugs to calm victims..."

Comment: There's also an air hug, with movements symbolizing an actual hug, without physical contact.

Comment: Hi can you guys check my updated question to see why I have this silly question in the first place ? lol And what is your answer for the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

A hug is an intimate form of physical contact. Consider the simple handshake which symbolises mutual trust and friendship. Hugging someone, without uttering a single word, can show joy, deep affection or compassion.

There are other ways of demonstrating joy, affection and compassion without physical touch. We do this through **writing**, in a text or sending a card, in the way we **speak** on the phone and by the tone of our **voice**, and if someone is sad, we show we care by **listening**.

Comment: So will you agree with my son's teacher and consider my son's answer incorrect ?

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 why do you disagree with the teacher?

Comment: Imagine hearing some bad or great news over the phone. At the moment of receiving the news, touching, which would include hugging, kissing, or even giving them a "high five" would be impossible. The question says *apart from touch*, the student should understand that this includes any physical contact.